# Object assign key & value - if value is valid

Tags: javascript, object

I think it;s dirty/unwanted question.

I have object name **test**, I just try to assign key and values(if value is valid).

In this below example x,y,z  are variables, this variables are dynamic sometimes only we get value.

The below code is working fine, but I used everytime checked value is valid or not then i assign key and value into object.

Just I want to check some smart way to add key?

```js
var test = {
    a: "1",
    b: "2"
}
var x = "3";
//here x value is dynamic, sometimes only we get value.
if (x) {
    test.c = x;
}

var y = "4";
//here y value is dynamic, sometimes only we get value.
if (y) {
    test.d = y;
}

var z = "5";
//here z value is dynamic, sometimes only we get value.
if (z) {
    test.e = z;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

Comment: Are the tests always truthy-checkers, that is, `if (someVar) // assign someVar to prop of object` ?

Comment: So you want, if there is a key, add that key and value, if not add a new key and the value. am I correct?

Comment: "sometimes only we get value" what?

Comment: @sorxrob, x,y,z values are get from backend,

Comment: So do you want to keep keys in order a,b,c,d... whenever you add a new value to the object? Is that what you need?

Comment: Hi all, my code is working fine, just I want to find smart way to do this. I added x,y,z for sample only. but I have have more than 10 to 15 variables.

Comment: Add your final output too.

Comment: where are the rest of the variables? @RSKMR

Comment: @sorxrob, For example I add few only.

Comment: is it coming from another variable or what?

Comment: @sorxrob - yes, It will come from another variable.

Comment: wow then show that variable with complete variables right? so we can make a better code. @RSKMR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as in your code, the tests always check to see whether the value is truthy before adding to the object, you could use a `Proxy`:

```js
const test = {
    a: "1",
    b: "2"
};
const testProx = new Proxy(test, {
  set: (obj, prop, val) => {
    if (val) obj[prop] = val;
  }
});
testProx.c = 'foo';
testProx.d = null; // falsey, will fail the Proxy's test and will not be added to object
testProx.e = 'bar';
console.log(test);
```

If you need more complicated validating, such as different conditions for different keys, I'd suggest making an object indexed by key containing a function that returns whether the value for that key is valid:

```js
const test = {
    a: "1",
    b: "2"
};
// just an example of having different conditions, this is not DRY code:
const testConditions = {
  c: (v) => typeof v === 'string' && v[0] === 'c',
  d: (v) => typeof v === 'string' && v[0] === 'd',
  e: (v) => typeof v === 'string' && v[0] === 'e',
}

const testProx = new Proxy(test, {
  set: (obj, prop, val) => {
    if (testConditions[prop](val)) obj[prop] = val;
  }
});
testProx.c = 'ccc';
// does not start with 'd', will fail the Proxy's test and will not be added to object:
testProx.d = 'fff'; 
testProx.e = 'eee';
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Thanks, I expected like this only.

Comment: Possible to add the code (testProx ) inside the function ? It will use multiple places.

Comment: Inside which function? What are you referring to?

Comment: Expecting create new function, then will move that code(testProx ) there.. because I will use multiple places using same function.  Example I have test object, some other places have xxx object..

Comment: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Got it what i am trying to say?

Comment: It is very hard to understand you, but you can use `testProx` for multiple objects if you want, if you want different tests for different options, you could pass in a test object (the `testConditions`) to a function that returns the Proxy

Comment: Thanks.  I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in a shorthand way like:

```js
var x, y, z;

var test = {
  a: "1",
  b: "2",
  c: x || null,
  d: y || null,
  e: z || null
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

Bear in mind that `x,y,z` must be defined before your `test` variable or you'll get the error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined`.

And also you can do more type checking with your `x,y,z` variables, with following syntax:

```js
var x, y, z;

var test = {
  a: "1",
  b: "2",
  c: (x == 3 ? x : null),
  d: y ? y : null,
  e: z ? z : null
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

Comment: If the value is null or undefined then don;t add the key's (c,d,e)

Answer (score 0):

If it's coming from another variable then you can loop through that and check every key if the value is null and if not, add it to the test variable.

```js
const main = {
x: 1,
y: 2,
z: 3
}

const test = {
a: 11,
b: 12,
c: 13
}

Object.keys(main).forEach((key) => {
if (main[key]) {
 test[key] = main[key]
}
});

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the description of your question is not that much clear, I am answering assuming,

1. You need to validate every value you add into the object.
2. You are finally using the stringified object for further processing.
3. You need to automatically set the key for the values.

You may even use a proxy to do the same thing based on your requirement.

```js
var test = {
 currentKey:0,
 add:function(val){
  if(val){
   this[String.fromCharCode('a'.charCodeAt()+(this.currentKey++))]=val;
  }
 },
 toJSON:function(){
  let obj={...this};
  delete obj.currentKey;
  delete obj.toJSON;
  return obj;
    }
}

let x = 90;
test.add(90);

let y = null;
test.add(y);

let z = 89;
test.add(z);

console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```